# Android Bluetooth RSSI value different

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have implemented a receiver within my app that continually searches using Bluetooth and updates the server every 10 seconds with the available devices. One piece of information it returns is the RSSI value of the device. The code I use to get this value is:

```
    node.Rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI, Short.MIN_VALUE);
```

So this seemed to work fine at first, using my test phone (Galaxy S4) I got expected values such as -75 or -88. However I have now tried a different phone shown in the link below:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Waterproof-smartphone-Dustproof-Shockproof-Capacitive/dp/B00EZNSUPU/ref=pd_sim_sbs_ce_3?ie=UTF8&refRID=0YYHYTW6J2AVZK7DJJDJ

(Sorry if I'm not allowed to post this here, I'm not 100% on the rules, if there's a problem I'll happily remove it)

When using this phone with the same build of my app, the values for the RSSI range from 150-200.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? Another problem I'm having with the phone is that when Bluetooth is on my Wi-Fi connection will eventually disappear, again this doesn't happen with my Galaxy S4. Is this test phone really that bad? Or am I missing something..

Comment: the rssi values depend on the hardware of the device and vary even with physical obstructions between the ble-hardware and your device, so this can different. As far as the bluetooth wifi problem goes, this problem has been seen in multiple devices, again the quality and os-structure/bluetooth stack structure varies for different oem's, so its likely you aren't missing anything, better try on multiple devices and check values for code performance